# How to create a new user in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to follow the docs to authenticate a new user into firebase but when my user sign up their information is not appearing in firebase authentication

So I tried turning my password/email text field into a string that might help get rid of this issue but I received this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField?' to expected argument type 'String'

so I tried using

> let{

But now I can't type into the text field at all to enter the user data into firebase so how do I properly set up this code to authenticate my new user data ?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
         let password  = Password.text
       let email = Email.text
         
               
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email!, password: password!) { authResult, error in
           
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                      return
              } else {
            }
```

Comment: It seems unexpected that the API would raise that error without reason. You might want to print the value of `Password.text!` right before you pass it to `createUser`.

Comment: It tell me Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField?' to expected argument type 'String' @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If you click that error you will see exactly where you are using a `UITextField`, where a `String` is expected.  Then [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+convert+value+of+type+%27UITextField%3F%27+to+expected+argument+type+%27String%27) and compare it to your code.

Comment: okay I started using {guard let} to create the string now I can't type at all in the text field @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different name for the variables, possibly lowercased instead of

```
let Password = Password.text
let Email = Email.text
```

use

```
let password = Password.text
let email = Email.text
```

in case the compiler is complaining and using the TextField instead of the text contained in it, or if you are using SwiftUI just pass a binging like so:

```
@State private var email: String = ""
@State private var password: String = ""

TextField("Email here...", text: $email)
SecureField("Password here...", text: $password)

Button {
  // ... check if fields are not null
  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { res, err in
    // ...
  }
} label: {
  Text("Create User")
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Try this and make sure to create the right segues with right names if you are copy pasting and also that the storyboard components are correctly configured and allow write text.

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func createUser(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = 
passwordTextField.text {
        // create the user with email and password
    }
}
```

Comment: I switched it to just let and used lowercase and its still giving me the same problem it won't let me type @alch_coder

Comment: Pretty strange, just for being sure,  have you lowercased the variable or the reference to the TextField? because the error `Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField?' to expected argument type 'String'` clearly says that it is receiving an UITextField as value instead of the actual string

Comment: I copy and pasted what you sent me to see if it would work let email  = Email.text  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email! and it didn't solve the problem still won't let me type @alch_coder

Comment: @Parlor can you share a little more of your code? if you have the repo for example, I would like to take a look

Comment: I updated the full code I used in the question @alch_coder

Comment: apdated the answer, also make sure that class name is correct

Comment: it took away the Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField?' to expected argument type 'String' but it still won't let me type @alch_coder

Comment: @Parlor have you checked the settings of the TextField on the storyboard file?

Comment: yeah it was a issue on my end I had to connect the keyboard on the stimulator thank you so much @alch_coder

Comment: glad to be helpful